# How to add django-filter Rangefilter class?

Tags: django, django-filter

I am try to add bootstrap class in to price range filter but i can't,

```
import django_filters
from panel.models import Product, Category,Size,TopNote, BaseNote, MidNote
from django import forms

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
 price = django_filters.RangeFilter(
            # widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
    )
 class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields =['name',
                 'category_id',
                 'price',
                 'top_notes', 'base_notes', 'category_id', 'size']
```

when I am add class using widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}) range filter convert into 1 textbox i dont't know why ???/

Answer (score 1):

The `RangeFilter` filter does not use the `TextInput` widget. Instead, it uses the `RangeWidget` widget to produce more than one input field.

```
from django_filters.widgets import RangeWidget

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    price = django_filters.RangeFilter(
        widget = RangeWidget(attrs={'class':'form-control'})
    )
    ...
```

The [documentation](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html#widget) states::

> RangeWidget – this widget is used with RangeFilter to generate two form input elements using a single field.

Read also the documentation about [RangeWidget](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/widgets.html#rangewidget).

Comment: AttributeError: module 'django.forms' has no attribute 'RangeWidget' error getting

Comment: It is `RangeWidget` from `django_filters.widgets`. I've edited my answer.